# Model field depends on other -

Tags: c#, exception

The following code gives me a

> System.StackOverflowException 
>   *{ Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state. }*

How can I define a field inside my Model which depends on others?

```
public class User : IMandatoryFields
{
    public byte Active
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Active == 1 && this.LocalActive == 1 && this.GlobalActive == 1) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
        set { this.Active = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are referring to Active inside the get of the Active property it keeps looping over until stack overflows.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a private property also:

```
    public class User : IMandatoryFields
    {
    private byte active;
    public byte Active
        {
            get
            {
                if (active == 1 && this.LocalActive.HasValue &&
this.LocalActive.Value == 1 && 
this.GlobalActive.HasValue &&  
this.GlobalActive.Value== 1) return 1;
                else return 0;
            }
            set { active = value; }
        }
    }
     public byte? LocalActive { get; set; } 
     public byte? GlobalActive { get; set; }
```

Comment: With private _active I don't get the exception and seems to work fine. Why should I have private property for other two fields?

Comment: You mean for LocalActive and GlobalActive? (you don't need  private properties for them unless you have missed some extra code in the initial post)

Comment: I added code for these fields. See above. So do I have to define a private property for LocalActive and GlobalActive too?

Comment: No you do not, but why are those properties nullable?, you must add some null checks also inside the Active gettter, or else the code might crash.